# Quitar opción descargar de etiqueta <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Estoy usando bootstrap 3 y tengo este código:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="archivos/pelicula.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es quitar la opción de descargar de los controles del video que se esta visualizando.

Se que usando la etiqueta `<video>`, solo con poner `controlslist="nodownload"` se desaparece esa opción pero desde la etiqueta `<iframe>` no he podido hacerlo, y lo pongo con `<iframe>` porque así lo ponen en la página de bootstrap.

Estoy usando el siguiente código jquery para acceder al contenido del iframe y hacer un cambio a ese contenido pero el problema es que no hace la modificación, supuesta mente si accede pero no realiza el cambio.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    quitarDescarga();
});

function quitarDescarga()
{
    var contenido = $("#vIFrame").contents().find("video").attr("controlslist", "nodownload");
}
```

Me di cuenta que este código funciona únicamente si se ejecuta desde un botón, como puedo hacer para que funcione desde el momento en que termina de cargar la página??

Comment: Has probado a acceder al contenido del iframe y editar la etiqueta `video`? [Un ejemplo de W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución que encontré es la siguiente:

Lo que necesitaba era quitar la opción de descarga del vídeo que se cargaba en la etiqueta `<iframe>`, gracias a la idea que me dio Jose en su comentario hice el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    quitarDescarga();
});

function quitarDescarga()
{
    var contenido = $("#vIFrame").contents().find("video").attr("controlslist", "nodownload");
}
```

Lo que sucedía aquí era que ejecutaba código al terminar de cargar la página, pero revisando a fondo me di cuenta que el código tenia que ejecutarse al terminar de cargar el contenido de la etiqueta `iframe` por lo que cambie mi código así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#vIFrame").load(function(){
        $(this).contents().find("video").attr("controlslist", "nodownload");
    });
});
```

Pero más sin embargo seguía teniendo problemas ya que me marcaba estos errores:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (pelicula.php:12)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Yo estaba usando la **api jquery de google versión 3.2.1**, y por alguna razón esta versión me dio conflicto con la función `load`, lo que hice como ultimo recurso fue cambiar a la **versión 1.11.2 de la api jquery de google** y con eso me funcionó de maravilla.